# How I can align edges?

Tags: modeling

I want align these edges in single even RED line?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Assuming that's an overhead view (numpad 7), with those faces selected, type 'Sz0' ENTER (Scale Z zero).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the red line is perpendicular to the X axis, just press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> as suggested by John Eason.

If your red line is parallel to the first face, and this face is not perpendicular to X, you can first push the other faces:

[image]

[image]

Then in top view use the *Knife* tool, <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, make sure it snaps to the 2 vertices of the edge so that it follows its direction:

[image]

Comment: Well. I never... New one on me. 'The point that Knife _would_ have snapped to, if I clicked there', just using the highlight. Great time-saver.

Comment: I didn't remember that actually, I just tested

Comment: Holy hell. How long has that feature been there? I don't use knife that often, but this is game changing. Great find!

Comment: knife is super useful! Seems like this feature was here in 2.7